# Issue in using application cache

Tags: html, caching, html5-appcache

Hi I'm trying to use application cache .As it is documented I'm getting a prompt like :

```
This website() is asking to store data on your computer for offline use .
```

with 3 options :

```
1.Allow 2. Never for this website 3. Not now
```

In my case only 3rd option works .Why?

Here is my html file

```
<html manifest="example.appcache">
.......
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'only the third option works'?  How have you tested it?  Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: Clicking on any of the 3 options should close the prompt but when I clicked on option 1 (Allow) and 2 (Never for this website) , the prompt didn't close .It closed only when I clicked on 3rd option (Not now).

Comment: Sounds like something is wrong with your browser then.

Comment: I'm not sure about it .I thought some settings may be required for using app cache .That's why I asked about it .Anyways thanks .I've dropped the idea for app cache and using localStorage !

Answer (score 0):

It's because you:

- either are hosting the appcache file locally on your computer, and your computer does not return the correct MIME to your browser: **text/cache-manifest**
- or your server (IIS/Apache) is not configured correctly to deliver the .appcaches files with the correct MIME.

For Apache you need to add this line to your .htaccess

```
AddType text/cache-manifest .appcache
```

For IIS, there are tutorials to be found if you search for "appcache IIS MIME"